Using the wolfram alpha API, is there a way to send a get request using JSON parameters and not encoded in the URL?
I'm working on a project that harnesses the Wolfram Alpha API in order to get a fast easy string response. The problem is that I need to be able to input a variable into it for the prompt input. The way the Wolfram alpha API works is that it requires inputs encoded in the URL itself, but this limits the ways you can pass inputs. I need a way to pass the inputs as JSON parameters, not areas in the URL.
I've been looking around and googling, but I can't find a good answer that says yes or no. I'm pretty new to APIs, wolfram alpha, and HTTP, so I appriciate any help I can get.

Typically APIs require that requests for data be made via a HTTP GET request. HTTP GET requests are URL encoded and do not have a request body (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET). This means that a JSON body cannot be attached. From a brief read through of the Wolfram Alpha API there is no POST request option possible (which is perfectly reasonable considering industry standards).
If you can provide a bit more context and code snippets there may be a work around for what you're attempting but at the moment there is insufficient information.
